# How is bracketing used in IC analysis?

Tags: syntax

Bracketing for [IC analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_constituent_analysis).
e.g.    `((The) (((happy) (teacher)) ((in) ((that) (class))))) ((was) ((beaming) (away))).`

Then, what about this sentence:

> "What happened next astonished all present at the meeting"

Comment: Welcome to the site! You expect others to spend time on your question, so it might be a good idea to show you also made some effort to answer it ;) Why don't you give us your attempt(s) at an analysis and point out where you are stuck or unsure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase (IC) "what happened next" is the subject of the sentence. The phrase "all present to the meeting" is the (direct) object. Thus, the basic IC structure is

```
[[what happened next] [VP [astonished] [all present at the meeting]]]
```

The object NP can be further analyzed as

```
[all [AP present [PP at [NP the meeting]]]]
```

The category labels depend on the theory used. In the heyday of syntactocentrism, for example, NPs with a determiner were believed to be "DPs". And in the Minimalist Program, there are no category labels at all. Nevertheless the basic IC division should be the same.

Comment: As far as i'm aware, the use of category labels is still fairly widespread in the MP. Of course, a more minimalist theory of the grammar *would* eliminate labels, and some people, like Chris Collins (see, e.g. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470755662.ch3/summary) have tried to do just that.

Comment: That really helps students understand syntax. Just give them the algorithm and they can load it in. Only one cavil with this answer, and that's that "what happened next" is in fact a clause, not a phrase, and needs an [NP [S S] NP] bracketing.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind answer, and here is my own try: (((what) (happened)) (next)) ((astonished) ((all) ((present) ((to) ((the) (meeting)))))). I don't know whether or not this is right.

Comment: @jlawler You're right, I simplified the solution by omitting the internal structure of the subject phrase. I think "what" will be a complementizer in the sentence, right?

Comment: It certainly functions as one, but it's got another coreferential role in the embedded question complement.